# akka stream consumer of rabbitmq with AMQP connector

Tags: java, rabbitmq, akka, akka-stream

I want to consume data from `rabbitMQ` queue with `akka stream` (`Java`). I took help from following link: http://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/latest/amqp.html

I would like to know about acknowledgement flow to `rabbitMQ` after element is consumed.

Can I consume the element in parallel? (Java snippet will be really helpful)

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify? Was there something specific you are looking for which the documentation on acknowledgements does not provide?

Comment: I want to consume rabbitmq with akka stream. I found that the akka stream with amqp connector, first pops the element from the queue, sends the acknowledgement to the queue and then sends the element to downstream(akka stream) to consume.

Comment: I want this acknowledgement in my control. Is this possible?

Comment: It sounds like you maybe need to pick another RabbitMQ client, if this "akka" tool doesn't do what you want it to do.  You certainly do have the option of fine control over acknowledgements with AMQP/RMQ.

Answer (score 2):

The current Alpakka AMQP connector does naive acking of messages as soon as they are emitted downstream, there is a ticket tracking adding a more flexible solution that you can follow here: https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/97